# How to extend the theme.mixins in MUI 5

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am in the process of upgrading Material UI from version 4 to 5, and I am having issues with some of my old theming.

We use typescript, so it's necessary to add the proper types when we want to extend the themes.

I want to add the following to the theme:

```js
...
 mixins: {
      toolbar: {
        minHeight: TOOLBAR_HEIGHT,
      },
      urlLink: {
        '&:link': {
          cursor: 'pointer',
          color: '#1a0dab',
        },
        '&:hover': {
          textDecoration: 'underline',
        },
        '&:visited': {
          color: '#609',
        },
      },
    },
...
```

The toolbar works without issue, however the urlLink section is unhappy.

In version 4, I had added the following to a file and it worked:

```js
mixins.ts
---------

import { CSSProperties } from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles'

declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createMixins' {
  interface Mixins {
    urlLink: CSSProperties
  }
  // allow configuration using `createMuiTheme`
  interface MixinsOptions {
    urlLink?: CSSProperties
  }
}
```

However now, after updating the imports, I am getting the following error:

```
Type '{ '&:link': { cursor: string; color: string; }; '&:hover': { textDecoration: string; }; '&:visited': { color: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''&:link'' does not exist in type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'
```

I don't fully understand how the type overrides work in general, so if someone can explain how to fix this problem or how they work in general, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 4):

Super late to answer this, and I sincerely hope you already figured this out, but just in case you're like me and you ended up on this page looking for this answer, here's what I believe you need to do.

In a file, usually near where you declare the properties object you are passing to createTheme, you would need a new module declaration that looks like this:

```
mixins.ts
---------

import { CSSProperties } from "@mui/material/styles/createMixins";

declare module "@mui/material/styles/createMixins" {
  // Allow for custom mixins to be added
  interface Mixins {
    urlLink?: CSSProperties
  }
}
```

The documentation around this is located here currently:
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#custom-variables

Hope this helps!